# Setting category and type for multiple columns possible?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a dataset which contains 6 columns `TIME1` to `TIME6`, amongst others. For each of these I need to apply the code below (which is shown for 2 columns). `LISTED` is a prepared list of the possible elements to be seen in these columns.

Is there a way to do this without writing the same 2 lines 6 times?

```
df['PART1'] = df['TIME1'].astype('category')
df['PART1'].cat.set_categories(LISTED, inplace=True)

df['PART2'] = df['TIME2'].astype('category')
df['PART2'].cat.set_categories(LISTED, inplace=True)
```

For `astype`(first line of code), I tried the following:

```
for col in ['TIME1', 'TIME2', 'TIME3', 'TIME4', 'TIME5', 'TIME6']:
    df_col = df[col].astype('category')
```

I think this works (not sure how to check without the whole code working). But how could I do something similar for the second line of code with the set_categories etc?

In short, I'm looking for something short/more elegant that just copying and modifying the same 2 lines 6 times.
I am new to python, any help is greatly appreciated.

Using python 2.7 and pandas 0.24.2

Comment: Try `df_col = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=LISTED)` instead?

Comment: I then need to join these 6 columns to another one from the dataset, I do so using this: `'col_1 = ['ELEMENTID']`
`new_col = df_col.join(col_1)`   But it gives me an error: `AttributeError: 'Categorical' object has no attribute 'join'.`   Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible! We can change the dtype of multiple columns to categorical is one go by creating `CategoricalDtype`

```
i = pd.RangeIndex(1, 7).astype(str)
df['PART' + i] = df['TIME' + i].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(LISTED))
```